# How can I make it so one lights turns off and on then the other comes on

Tags: javascript, html, css

With my code, the "lights" turn on one at a time and then turn off one at a time but I want there to only be one light on at a time. I want the previously turned on light to turn off before the next one comes on.

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshKerr98/hrpasw0p/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var colourInfo = [
        { id: 'square2id', color: ['#FFFF00','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square3id', color: ['#00FF00','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square4id', color: ['#0000FF','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square1id', color: ['#FFFFFF','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square5id', color: ['#FFA500','#000000'] },  
    ];

    var changeIndex = 0, colorIndex = 0;

    var changeNextBoxColor = function() {
        if (!colourInfo[changeIndex]) {
            changeIndex = 0;
            colorIndex += 1;
        }

        var info = colourInfo[changeIndex],
            color = info.color[colorIndex%info.color.length];


        $('#' + info.id).css('background-color', color);

        changeIndex += 1;

        setTimeout(changeNextBoxColor, 2000);
    };

    setTimeout(changeNextBoxColor, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read through the comments as well.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dehli/g5qqrzqm/9/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colourInfo = [
        { id: 'square2id', color: ['#FFFF00','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square3id', color: ['#00FF00','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square4id', color: ['#0000FF','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square1id', color: ['#FFFFFF','#000000'] },
        { id: 'square5id', color: ['#FFA500','#000000'] }
    ];

    var colorIndex = 0;

    // This function sets the color of a box with a certain id
    var setColor = function(squareId, color) {
        $('#' + squareId).css('background-color', color);
    };

    // This will make the colorIndex's box black, then increment the index
    // and highlight the next box
    var changeNextBoxColor = function() {
        // Need to make sure to mod (%) by the length of colourInfo
        // so that the index doesn't go out of bounds.
        var revertSquare = colourInfo[colorIndex % colourInfo.length];
        setColor(revertSquare.id, revertSquare.color[1]);

        // By using ++colorIndex, you increment colorIndex and the left hand value is
        // the incremented value so that changeSquare corresponds to the next element
        // in colourInfo
        var changeSquare = colourInfo[(++colorIndex) % colourInfo.length];
        setColor(changeSquare.id, changeSquare.color[0]);
    };

    // This repeats the function every 2 seconds (so you don't need to call setTimeout
    // inside of changeNextBoxColor).
    setInterval(changeNextBoxColor, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Dehli.

Comment: @JoshKerr You're welcome. If it answered your question, please make sure to mark it as the answer. :)